# RegexKitLite - iOS: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, regexkitlite

I have a project that must use regular expressions, so I decided to use **RegexKitLite**, I downloaded it, have added *RegexKitLite.m* into "Compile Sources", and *RegexKitLite.h* into "Copy Files" sections. Added **libicucore.A.dylib** to project Libraries. Imported *RegexKitLite.h* into my class, and write code (just for test):

```
        NSString *str = @"testing string";
        if ([str isMatchedByRegex:@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Some message here");
        }
```

After that I have error message:

```
-[__NSCFString isMatchedByRegex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed45ac0
2013-02-28 19:46:20.732 TextProject[8467:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isMatchedByRegex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed45ac0'
```

What I have missed? Please help me..

Comment: Did u declare you header file: #import "RegexKitLite.h" in your implementation file?

Comment: I have imported "RegexKitLite.h" into my header class

Comment: Is it for Mac OS or iOS because this lib seems to be available only for MacOS. You are also trying to import a dynamic lib which is not allowed on iOS.

Comment: there is iOS libs here http://www.ioslib.com/library/utilities/regexkitlite/ thats it.. RegexKitLite is availible for iOS

Comment: RegexKitLite: Lightweight Objective-C Regular Expressions for Mac OS X using the ICU Library? this is from ur link: i am confused...

Comment: RegEx are part of iOS4 it doesn't make sense to me to use this.

Comment: I'd use [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) unless you had a reason to not use the standard Cocoa regular expression class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging there wasn't in fact any Cocoa API to use regex before iOS4 so programmers were using external libraries like RegexKitLite which indeed could be used for iOS.

If you are on iOS4 or later there shouldn't be any reason not to use NSRegularExpression. Class reference description can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW48).

For example with `NSRegularExpression` your code snippet will look like:

```
NSString *str = @"testing string";   
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSString* matchingString = [str substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@", matchingString);
}
```